# JEditorPane html document inline (embedded) image from file

Tags: java, html, swing, base64, jeditorpane

I'm trying to inline (embed) an image in a JEditorPane from a file such as:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;utf-8,data...">
```

But I'm struggling with the code.

So far I have (assuming a gif file):

```
try
{
    File imageFile = new File("C:\\test\\testImage.gif"); 
    File htmlFile = new new File("C:\\test\\testOutput.html");

    byte[] imageBytes = Files.toByteArray(imageFile);
    String imageData = new String(imageBytes, "UTF-8");

    String html = "<html><body><img src=\"data:image/gif;utf-8," + imageData + "\"></body></html>";

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(htmlFile, htmlText);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This does create a file but the image is invalid. I'm sure I'm not converting the image the proper way...

Comment: Btw, I don't really care about the encoding, it could be base64.

Comment: I was able to get this to work.  Explanation is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943833/how-to-render-a-internal-image-on-a-swing-component-using-html/27921370#27921370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JEditorPane` (and Java HTML rendering in general) does not support Base64 encoded images.

Of course 'does not' != 'could not'.

The thing is, you'd need to create (or adjust) an [`EditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/EditorKit.html) can have new elements defined.  An e.g. is seen in the [`AppletEditorKit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073804/418556).  You'd need to look for `HTML.tag.IMG` - it is is a standard image, call the `super` functionality, else use [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12498256/418556) (or similar) to convert it to an image, then embed it.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a way so I have to believe your answer :(