# How to render a internal image on a swing component using html?

Tags: java, html, swing

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "<html><body>test<br><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\"></body></html>");
    pane.setEditable(false);
    frm.getRootPane().setContentPane(pane);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is render a image on the JEditorPane using base64 codification to store the image. It does not need to be base64, but that's as far as I got while trying to render HTML content on the JEditorPane, but I need to use an image that is on a BufferedImage(It is generated by the application.), and, would really prefer not to have to save the image to a file in the hard disk.

Can I, somehow, display an BufferedImage in a swing component along with HTML(displaying it in the place given by the IMG tag - the html code is generated by the application too)?

Comment: Do you want to save the image which contains your `JEditorPane` with html content as you see it when running the app?

Comment: No, I want to display a BASE64 or BufferedImage in the JEditorPane, using html to insert it with text and other elements. I got one solution, but it's ugly and big... Posted it as an answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to rewrite one of the Java classes and extend another, but got the BASE64 image working under HTML on the JEditorPane. I'll post my solution in case someone needs it in the future...

First, create a Special HTMLEditorKit that will use the rewritten ImageView class for the HTML.Tag.IMG

```
class BASE64HTMLEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {

    private static HTMLFactory factory = null;

    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new HTMLFactory() {

                @Override
                public View create(Element elem) {
                    AttributeSet attrs = elem.getAttributes();
                    Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
                    Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
                    if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {
                        HTML.Tag kind = (HTML.Tag) o;
                        if (kind == HTML.Tag.IMG) {
                            // HERE is the call to the special class...
                            return new BASE64ImageView(elem);
                        }
                    }
                    return super.create(elem);
                }
            };
        }
        return factory;
    }

}
```

With that done, implement the special class, based on the openjdk code.
Download the source code [here](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/), and open the file openjdk/jdk/src/share/classes/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.java. Because it have almost everything private, I found it easier to copy it entirely and then change the method needed to load BASE64 Images:

```
private void loadImage() {
    String b64 = getBASE64Image();
    BufferedImage newImage = null;
    try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(b64))) {
        newImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ...
    }
    image = newImage;
}

private String getBASE64Image() {
    String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
    if (src == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return src.replaceFirst("data:image/png;base64,", "");
}
```

The getBASE64Image method just cuts the non BASE64 part of the attribute.
The loadImage method is the one that has to be changed, and if it where public, would have helped cut a lot of code from the solution...

If someone has a better and preferably smaller (mine have 1000 lines of code), please share it...

Answer (score 2):

By piecing these posts and some from other sources, I was able to get to get this to work for myself.

If I used the above paintComponent() function, it paints the image but any additional html items aren't display properly because they overwrite each other.  To fix this, I tried to minimize the methods which were modified and this approach seemed to work.

Anyways, this is what I did to get it working: 
1) Download the OpenJDK7 files from http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/
2) Unzip the file and copy the openjdk/jdk/src/share/classes/javax/swing/text/html/ImageView.java to your project's src folder  (Use a different name than ImageView.java.  In the following example, we will call it Custom_ImageView.java).  You will have to modify this file, so open it in your text editor and do the following:
2A) Change the class name from "ImageView" to "Custom_ImageView".
2B) Change the constructor name from "ImageView" to "Custom_ImageView".

```
public ImageView(Element elem) {
      ...to...
public Custom_ImageView(Element elem) {
```

2C) Change all "synchronized(ImageView.this)"  to  "synchronized(Custom_ImageView.this)"
2D) Change the loadImage() to this:

```
// Modified method in Custom_ImageView.java
private void loadImage() {
    URL src = getImageURL();        
    Image newImage = null;
    if (src != null) {
        Dictionary cache = (Dictionary)getDocument().
                                getProperty(IMAGE_CACHE_PROPERTY);
        if (cache != null) {
            newImage = (Image)cache.get(src);                
        }
        else {                 
            newImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(src);                                
            if (newImage != null && getLoadsSynchronously()) {
                // Force the image to be loaded by using an ImageIcon.
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon();
                ii.setImage(newImage);
            }
        }
    } else {  // BEGIN:  Modified code...              
        //System.out.println("[DEBUG] Image Source:  " + src);
        System.out.println("[DEBUG] loadImage() - newImage = null");
        String b64 = getBASE64Image();        
        BufferedImage newBufferedImage = null;
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(b64))) {
            newBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] in loadImage() \n\t" + ex);
        } // End catch()...
        newImage = newBufferedImage;
    }  // FINISH: Modified code...
    image = newImage;
}
```

Compared the above snippet to the original code:

```
// Original code from ImageView.java (OpenJDK7)...
private void loadImage() {
    URL src = getImageURL();
    Image newImage = null;
    if (src != null) {
        Dictionary cache = (Dictionary)getDocument().
                                getProperty(IMAGE_CACHE_PROPERTY);
        if (cache != null) {
            newImage = (Image)cache.get(src);
        }
        else {
            newImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(src);
            if (newImage != null && getLoadsSynchronously()) {
                // Force the image to be loaded by using an ImageIcon.
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon();
                ii.setImage(newImage);
            }
        }
    }
    image = newImage;
}
```

2E) Within the Custom_ImageView class, add a method called getBASE64Image(), this is used by the modified loadImage() method:

```
// Add this method to Custom_ImageView.java
private String getBASE64Image() {
    String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes().getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
    if (src == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // This doesn't account for "data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,"
    //return src.replaceFirst("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    // So I delete all data from beginning of line (^) to ";base64"
    return src.replaceFirst("^.*;base64,", "");
} // End getBASE64Image()...
```

This finishes up the Custom_ViewImage.java modifications. 
3) Now we need to create our own HTMLEditorKit which will be used by our JEditorPane.  We will call this file Custom_HTMLEditorKit.java.  As stated above, we will need to override the getViewFactory() method so that it knows to use our modified file (Custom_ImageView).  The code should look like this:

```
package my.app.package;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.View;
import javax.swing.text.ViewFactory;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTML;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class Custom_HTMLEditorKit extends HTMLEditorKit {
    private static HTMLFactory factory = null;    

    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        if (factory == null) {
            factory = new HTMLFactory() {

                @Override
                public View create(Element elem) {
                    AttributeSet attrs = elem.getAttributes();
                    Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
                    Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
                    if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {
                        HTML.Tag kind = (HTML.Tag) o;
                        if (kind == HTML.Tag.IMG) {
                            // HERE is the call to the special class...
                            return new Custom_ImageView(elem);
                        } // End if(kind == IMG)...
                    } // End if(instance of Tag)...
                    return super.create(elem);
                } // End create()...                
            }; // End new HTMLFactory()...
        } // End if(factory == null)...
        return factory;
    } // End getViewFactory()... 
} // End Custom_HTMLEditorKit()...
```

4) Now we are ready to use the code.  Within our main app, you just have to reassign the HTMLEditorKit to Custom_HTMLEditorKit.

```
package my.app.package;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class ExpInlineImage {

    public ExpInlineImage() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
        jep.setEditable(false);
        jep.setContentType("text/html");
        jep.setEditorKit(new Custom_HTMLEditorKit());
        jep.setText(
                  "<html><body>test<br><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw"
                + "0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAACuklEQVR42sWVv09TU"
                + "RTH71AXE40xaRdXEwbD4ODiIFr6EwcXN1cnR0cXoyTWUjcH3n0dDG4aEwca"
                + "oqggWn8ERWtoKdVBoA2lxbj4BxzPt+eaPEn7nhDeleRDTr733vP9vtvXU0V"
                + "E6n8i//79L5KdUKVUXtHobUXxnIAaGtawZzcNdxvgEIw2u0Va39SMa9A9DW"
                + "vYE2aAKJ4WhpPTipySgBoa1rAnzAAxXPnalkvOjCL3iYAaGtawJ/QA650ia"
                + "TYuPhVQQ7MbAOazAmqrAdb4hXOe8fW/EFBDsxdgmwM8Z/M5ATU0ewF+cACY"
                + "vxRQQ7MS4NwtRd9xA/NsviCghoa1vQaIjP2ZcLnBxNng9E1F37p3yYH5awE"
                + "1NKxhj18PeIx5J6YJ0Jtwaz/vUKObZwoDqW8VaL5xkfQr/gaUBdTQsOZ3Fr"
                + "3h8dfENAGiCU5X79ygSW7oBKDf8JO/ZXMDamhB59AbHomcZ2KaADGIy+1r5"
                + "HAjjabv+lMMYNA59ERveCS8L6s3QKV9lRxsfs+H9hn0RG94DAyw1L5CepEP"
                + "fOCn8cFd7I/vGQa94dE3QJpfjMr2ZZr6oui+D/c+c8OP0tALNKz5nUVveKT"
                + "zfQKcL6hfmQnVWxxEin9uR8YVlVuXSC+xsQE1NKxhj18PeCSuq/LOl/AIc5"
                + "KJM6M+ZHB9C60LpD+xuQE1NHO1mYAeI8yJnV/DAyZELIChJJvMtVKkK2xuQ"
                + "A0tKQGGAnpEjXlkT6M4xSazzTPk8ufpBVrKxm8BTGaap8itsvGyoSqatQCl"
                + "jWFya2LcoyaatQCPW8dJr/BnXzOsiGYtwKPmMdKrbFw3rIpmJUCaTR60jlL"
                + "xK199Q0ANLW0jQJaHycPOQZpq8mTbMDRFy+bDDxDNjKsqjPC0XqAlvRMupA"
                + "CHmWHmbOCECylAxISIBk64kALs+99vkl5XSNCDZhMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
                + "\"></body></html>");

        jf.getRootPane().setContentPane(jep);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    } // End constructor...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExpInlineImage app = new ExpInlineImage();
    } // End main()...

} // End ExpInlineImage{}...
```

5) Run the app and you should see an image of a green plus sign below the word "test". 

 
Some things worth mentioning: 
  * border="1" seems to work fine.  This will draw a border around the image. 
  * width="100px" works fine. Sets width to 100 pixels regardless of original size. 
  * width="100" works fine.  Sets width to 100 pixels regardless of original size. 
  * width="50%" doesn't work.  This sets the width to 50 pixels instead of 50 percent of original size.

For those interested, I posted the example on github.  
 
https://github.com/GreenElm/expInlineImage/tree/master/src/expinlineimage

Or download repo by...

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/GreenElm/expInlineImage.git
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

An other way to hook an ImageView:

```
public class Base64ImageView extends ImageView {

private URL url;

public Base64ImageView(Element elem) {
    super(elem);

    populateImage();
}

private void populateImage() {
    Dictionary<URL, Image> cache = (Dictionary<URL, Image>) getDocument()
            .getProperty("imageCache");
    if (cache == null) {
        cache = new Hashtable<URL, Image>();
        getDocument().putProperty("imageCache", cache);
    }

    URL src = getImageURL();
    cache.put(src, loadImage());

}

private Image loadImage() {
    String b64 = getBASE64Image();
    BufferedImage newImage = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    try {
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                Base64.decodeBase64(b64.getBytes()));
        newImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
    }
    return newImage;
}

private String getBASE64Image() {
    String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes()
            .getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
    if (!isBase64Encoded(src)) {
        return null;
    }
    return src.substring(src.indexOf("base64,") + 7, src.length() - 1);
}

@Override
public URL getImageURL() {
    String src = (String) getElement().getAttributes()
            .getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.SRC);
    if (isBase64Encoded(src)) {

        this.url = Base64ImageView.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource().getLocation();

        return this.url;
    }
    return super.getImageURL();
}

private boolean isBase64Encoded(String src) {
    return src != null && src.contains("base64,");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can NOT display an BufferedImage within an HTML-Tag!

you can create an BufferedImage without saving it, you can create a BufferedImage from an URI/URL and you can display HTML within most swing components, but you can't do both in one;

maybe you can customize your swing component by overriding the paintComponent method and paint html and then image (maybe you want to to it the other way round).

```
private BufferedImage buffImg; //won't be stored

private void readImage(){
    URL url = URI.create("myUri").toURL();
    buffImg = ImageIO.read(url);
}


@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics gr){
    super(gr); //draws your html code        
    gr.drawImage(buffImg, x, y, obs); //draweing the buffImage
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I would have to keep track of the image parameters outside of the html String, or parse it to get the attributes, such as size and position...