# Show images in BrowserPane CSSbox

Tags: java, html, r, swing, knitr

I am trying to render an html document in a Swing application ussing [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/manual/)

The html is produced from knitr in R.

The html document shows fine apart from the images which do not. I do not understand why. I get a generated error which shows:

```
WARN  Obtained a zero intrinsic width or height for ReplacedImage [url=data:i.....]
```

My code for the CSSBox:

```
 BrowserPane brwsrpnEee = new BrowserPane();
                brwsrpnEee.setContentType("");
 brwsrpnEee.setPage(ftohtml.toURI().toURL());
```

My code from the relevant part of R (using spin from knitr):

```
#' ---
#' title: Sample HTML report generated from R script
#' author: Sebastian Zeki
#' date: November 12th, 2016
#' output:
#'    html_document:
#'      toc: true
#'      highlight: zenburn
#' ---

#+results='asis', echo=FALSE
knitr::kable(FinalTable, digits = 2, caption = 'A table produced by printr.')
#'## This is a bad ass graph what I made
#+mygraph='svg', dev='svg',echo=FALSE
TBB
```

the html image looks like this (the ... is my addition):

```
   <h2>This is my graph</h2>

    <p><img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmN.....
...vc3ZnPgo=" alt="plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2"/> </p>

</body>

</html>
```

I suspect that the lack of image width and height is the culprit so I changed the R code to

```
#+mygraph='svg', dev='svg',echo=FALSE,fig.height=4, fig.width=8,out.width = "400px",out.height="400px"
```

This gets incorporated into the img tag fine as

but it just leaves an empty box with no image.

How can I see the image?

Comment: Link to the JavaDocs for `BrowserPane` ..

Comment: Hi. I have added the link to CSSBox documentation in the first line.

Comment: All I could find was http://book2s.com/java/src/package/org/fit/cssbox/swingbox/browserpane.html

Answer (score 1):

From the source seen in [Source code for `BrowserPane` from package `org.fit.cssbox.swingbox`](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/org/fit/cssbox/swingbox/browserpane.html):

```
public class BrowserPane extends JEditorPane {
```

Oops! That would explain it, because `JEditorPane` does not support data images.

```html
<img src="data:image/ ... " ..>
```

Comment: I note you posted a workaround with Appleteer once upon a time but seems unreachable now.....

Comment: That was for implementing a new element for `applet`. I'm not sure if it can be used for changing the behaviour for existing elements. The code for `AppletEditorKit` can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16073804/418556). To convert a data URI to an image, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19239626/418556) (& the linked information).

Comment: Oh, now looking at `AppletEditorKit` more closely, it seems it should be possible. It's been a while since I looked at the code. :P

Comment: But where is org.pscode.ui.applet.appleteer. I can't find the classes anywhere on the internet

Comment: *"But where is org.pscode.ui.applet.appleteer."* Why? I lost my site and Appleteer became irrelevant when most browsers dropped support for applets.

Comment: BTW - you'd be better off searching on 'jeditorpane custom htmleditorkit' (than appleteer itself)..

Comment: Was hoping to do a cut 'n paste job with your appleteer code as all I want to do is view the embedded svgs but will have to spend another few hours trawling through the tricky code.....what doesn't kill you just makes you weaker...:(

Comment: I did not look at the data URI closely enough & just noticed `svg+xml`. Note that the assumption in the *"To convert a data URI to an image, see .."* link presumes the JRE supports the image type, and the core JRE sure does not support `svg+xml.

Comment: I have also output the image without it being svg with the same issue